# Open a pop up for a single item in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the list of items. But i am showing one of the sample code.

I have the following HTML code

```
<div id="starpline_timestamp_refer" title="Refer your friends" style="margin-left:10px;"><a class="refer_freinds" id="39342" href="javascript:void(0);">Refer your friends</a></div>

<div class='strapline_share_buttons' style='display:none;'>".elgg_view("addthis/extend", $vars)."</div>
```

This is repeating for ten times but i have the different id for all buttons like `id="39342"`
So when i click the `refer your friends` button the `strapline_share_buttons` is opening for all items so i need to show for one item.

My jQuery:

```
$("a.refer_freinds").click(function(){
        var item_id =  $(this).attr("id"); 
        //$( ".strapline_share_buttons").toggle();
        $(this).$( ".strapline_share_buttons").toggle();
        });
        $(".strapline_share_buttons").popup("open", {
            "transition": "pop"
        });
```

So how to do it?

Comment: $(this).$( ".strapline_share_buttons").toggle(); what is this ..remove $

Comment: No after removing its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understood question and html layout, this code must be working.

```
$("a.refer_freinds").click(function () {
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    //go to parent and next element in DOM and show that
    //<div class='strapline_share_buttons' style='display:none;'>".elgg_view("addthis/extend", $vars)."</div>

    $(this).parent().next().show()
        .popup("open", {
        "transition": "pop"
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9H9jq/2/

Comment: Okay its working fine but can we again toggle that if outside cliking the box or inside clicking the box ?? Box means which was toggled earlier...

Comment: May change $(this).parent().next().show() to $(this).parent().next().toggle() this will toggle element then we clicked to <a> link.

Comment: For example, may add this event listener $(this).parent().next().click(function(){$(this).hide();}); this hiding <div> when that clicked.

Comment: No we need to use the mouse up fuction...any way thnx for ur effort & time.....here your first answer will be accepted...

Comment: @Magistr_AVSH how would you do that in this very same example, that "Refers your friends" only shows the actual referral number? I mean, if there are other shown referral numbers, then it closes them in parallel with showing it's own ref num? thank you in advance